# Analog of TestNG data provider in Spock

Tags: java, testing, groovy, testng, spock

I'm new to Spock, and currently switching to it, but I inherited plenty of test configuration files which need to be re-used. Each config file is a JSON, having the same name as Spec class. For each test method there is a list of maps with parameters, e.g.:

```
LoginSpec.json:
{
  "My first test": [
    {
      "user": "user_one",
      "role": "ADMIN"
    },
    {
      "user": "user_two",
      "role": "REPORTER",
      "other_param": "other"
    }
  ],

  "Some Other Test Method": [
    {
      "url": "/lab1",
      "button_name": "Show news popup"
    }
  ]
}
```

**TestNG** allowed me to pass test method name in data provider method, so I could return the list of maps depending on test class name and test method name. I had only one data provider method in my base class:

```
public Object[][] getData(String method) {
    DataReader reader = new JsonReader()
    return reader.parse(packageFullName, getClass().simpleName, method)
}
```

As a result of this method I get an array of Maps to use in each of test iteration. And then I just specify this method as a DataProvider:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "getData", priority = 1)
void EULA_1(Map data) { <====
    Pages.login.openLoginPage()
    Pages.login.logIn(data.user) <====
    ...
}
```

This works perfectly: declared ones in the base class, it automatically receives the test and provides test data.

**The question is:** is there a way to apply similar approach in Spock tests?

I'd like to have some getData() method in my base class, where I'm able to read tests parameters depending on the test method name and then pass them into **where** block.

I tried to use my json reader as shown below:

```
def "My first test"() {
    setup:
    println(data)

    when:
    ...
    then:
    ...

    where:
    data = dataReader.parse("JobE2E", "LoginSpec.json", "My first test")
}
```

This example gives me required list of maps, but has two problems:

1. **data** here - is the full list of maps, not one map for each iteration;
2. I'm forced to explicitly type the name of test method, class etc.

**Summing up:** 
What is the best way to implement a data provider which will receive test method name and return a list of maps?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve problem with `data` using this approach:

```
data << dataReader.parse('JobE2E', "${getClass().name}.json", 'My first test')
```

It will iterate the list of maps so each test iteration will be parametrized only by that map.

---

Current test name can be obtained by:

```
specificationContext.currentFeature.name
```

And current iteration name by:

```
specificationContext.currentIteration.name
```

But both are not accessible in the `where` section because it is executed before the test itself where only values from shared context are available. <strike>So here I'm afraid that you have to enter the test name manually.</strike>

**Update:** I found solution how to get feature name in `where` section for you. It is realized by an own extension using interceptor.

Feature details container:

```
class FeatureDetails {
    String name
}
```

Extension annotation:

```
import org.spockframework.runtime.extension.ExtensionAnnotation

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType
import java.lang.annotation.Retention
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy
import java.lang.annotation.Target

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@ExtensionAnnotation(FeatureDetailsExtension.class)
@interface ShareFeatureDetails {
}
```

Spock extension with inline interceptor implementation:

```
import org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractAnnotationDrivenExtension
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.FeatureInfo

class FeatureDetailsExtension extends AbstractAnnotationDrivenExtension<ShareFeatureDetails> {
    def featureDetails = new FeatureDetails()

    @Override
    void visitFeatureAnnotation(ShareFeatureDetails annotation, FeatureInfo feature) {
        feature.addInterceptor({ i ->
            featureDetails.name = feature.name
            feature.spec.allFields.each { f ->
                if (f.type == FeatureDetails.class && f.readValue(i.getInstance()) == null) {
                    f.writeValue(i.getInstance(), featureDetails)
                }
            }
            i.proceed()
        })
    }
}
```

Example usage of the extension:

```
class DataProviderSpec extends Specification {
    @Shared
    FeatureDetails currentFeature

    @Unroll("Test #data.a * 2 = #data.b")
    @ShareFeatureDetails
    def 'test'() {
        when:
        println data

        then:
        data.a * 2 == data.b

        where:
        data << loadData()
    }

    @Unroll("Test #data.a * 3 = #data.b")
    @ShareFeatureDetails
    def 'another test'() {
        when:
        println data

        then:
        data.a * 3 == data.b

        where:
        data << loadData()
    }

    def loadData() {
        // this is hard coded example
        println "${getClass().name}.${currentFeature.name}"
        if ('test' == currentFeature.name) return [[a: 1, b: 2], [a: 2, b: 4]]
        if ('another test' == currentFeature.name) return [[a: 3, b: 9], [a: 4, b: 12]]
        return []
        // ... use load from data file (JSON, YAML, XML, ...) instead:
        // return dataReader.parse("${getClass().name}.json", currentFeature.name)
    }
}
```

And the output of above example:

> DataProviderSpec.test
>   [a:1, b:2]
>   [a:2, b:4]
>   DataProviderSpec.another test
>   [a:3, b:6]
>   [a:4, b:8]

First idea was to use only annotated `String featureName` field in the spec class but there is a problem where `visitFeatureAnnotation()` method works with different spec instance during each call while `loadData()` method is executed each time on the first instance.

---

**Note:** You can also add description with values specific to the current iteration using `@Unroll` annotation. For example:

```
@Unroll("Test #data.a * 2 = #data.b")
def 'test'() {
    setup:
    ...
    when:
    ...
    then:
    data.a * 2 == data.b

    where:
    data << getData('test')
}

def getData(String methodName) {
    if ('test' == methodName) return [[a: 1, b: 2], [a: 2, b: 4]]
    ...
}
```

Will produce:

> Test 1 * 2 = 2
>   Test 2 * 2 = 4

Comment: Yep, thank you. This is very similar to what I have now: getData(Stirng name) method in base spec class, where I get class name and package. But I still forced to duplicate spec name in getData when calling it in where block. Really no change to get spec name there?

Comment: I found solution how to get feature name in the where section and updated the answer accordingly. It is realized by a simple own Spock extension. I hope it will help to you.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something, but this solution suggests to list all the specs' names in dataprovider, in order to use if statements. This is still code duplication.

Comment: `loadData()` method is only example of how it works - you can adapt it on your case and load data from JSON file instead of using if statements. So instead of `loadData()` you can use your: `dataReader.parse("JobE2E", "${getClass().name}.json", currentFeature.name)`

Comment: I read again your answer. Thank you, will try your extension!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`JsonSlurper`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html). It basically parses JSON and returns an Object which could be a List or a Map (just cast it). You can easily use it in your `were` block (remember to only use `static` or `@Shared` in there).

[Here](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) is some documentation about JSON in Groovy.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the answer, but it's not a question of how to parse JSON. I actually have a JSON parser which works okay for me and returns a map with params (I use Gson instead of JsonSlurper but no matter here). My question is how to implement passing required spec info into the parser. Does Spock have any kind of pre-test  hook where I can get test's name and load the params into list of maps and then put this list into where?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved.**

The following method, declared in the `BaseSpec` class, gets the name of current spec automatically on a stage of `where` block and load params from a config file accordingly:

```
    protected List<Map<String, Object>> getData() {
        String methodName = StackTraceUtils.sanitize(new Throwable()).stackTrace[1].methodName
        FeatureInfo spec = specificationContext.currentSpec.features.find {
            FeatureInfo info ->
                info.dataProviders.any {
                    it.dataProviderMethod.name == methodName
                }
        }
        Class className = getClass()
        String packageFullName = className.package.name
        String packageName = packageFullName[(packageFullName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1)..-1]
        TestDataReader reader = new JsonReader()
        return reader.parse(packageName, className.simpleName, spec.name)
    }
```

Usage in class, which is a subclass of `BaseSpec` class:

```
def "My custom name spec"() {

    when:
    ... 

    then: 
    ...

    where:
    data << getData()
}
```